# Logistic Regression coefficients when combining datasets

Tags: machine-learning, logistic

I am going over the machine learning qualifying exams for Georgia Tech and having a hard time coming up with a proof for this question. I feel like I understand it conceptually but cannot write it in proof. Any help would be appreciated![image]